# Mailman automatic approval for new message from a specific domain

Tags: linux, mailman

kindly all can you show how to configure mailman to approve all message from specific domain without a request to confirmation even if this domain sender is not subscribed ?

i tried this but not working, login as administrator then

Privacy options...> Sender filters > List of non-member addresses whose postings will be immediately held for moderation.
i added in this filter ^[^@]+@silminds.com$ as i need all senders @ silminds.com be accepted without any confirmation requests from moderators

please help

Comment: i found the answer in the following link as it explain in details the syntax and how to http://www.washington.edu/itconnect/email/mailman/regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Privacy Options->Sender filters->accept_these_nonmembers" and try:

^.*(silminds|uw).com$